# set size of image fix with text

Tags: html, css

I have a div of thumbnail with image, I want to set the size of image fix with text in it.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="/image/<%=dream.dreamimage%>"  alt="User image" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-user">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><%=dream.dreamtitle%></h3>
            <p><%=dream.dreamdiscription%></p>
            <p><%=dream.dreamlocation%></p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You want the image to be the background of the text, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the effect you're looking for. If I misunderstood from the description, let me know.

You need to set to inline-block so it doesn't attempt to fill the entire width, then use object-fit to cover the remaining space.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/2626231?s=460&v=4" class="image" />
  <p class="text">This is the text</p>
</div>
```